# Woocommerce Wordpress plugin not showing quantity on cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Strange issue this. When I 'add to cart' it is set to redirect straight to the cart contents page to push sales however when it then loads the cart contents page the qty box is empty however if I view source at this point, the qty is there in the code. If I just click go to checkout leaving it blank (on the assumption that it is simply not displaying but is actually seeing the qty) it tells me cart is empty.

Even stranger, if I refresh the page whilst looking at the 'blank qty cart page', the qty appears for a milisecond then disappears.

It took me a while to work out shipping methods but got there in the end so this is the only issue left to sort. I asked on the wordpress forums but getting no response so if anyone could help that'd be great. I would guess it is a css issue but really just not sure.

html of qty button in 'blank' state:

```
<td class="product-quantity">
<div class="quantity"><input type="number" name="cart[8c5f6ecd29a0eb234459190ca51c16dd]    [qty]" step="1" min="" max="" value="2" size="4" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text"   maxlength="12" /></div>
</td>
```

corresponding css (as far as I can see, the woocommerce.css file itself is quite big but I don't want to post all of it here)

```
.woocommerce td.product-quantity,.woocommerce-page td.product-quantity {
min-width:80px;
color:#fff;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Changing to a default theme such as 'Twenty Twelve' fixes the issue however as I don't want to do that I need to debug the current theme to see why this is happening. It can't be css as I tried actually deleting all the css from the theme and had the same issue. What else can I actually check?

Answer (score 0):

if you change your theme to the default, it works right ?

see here:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-product-quantity-not-showing-on-cart-page